# identifier u16 is underfined - unable to build project in VS2019,

Tags: c++, compilation, dependencies

So I've downloaded this project

```
https://github.com/Gemini-Loboto3/Mizzurna-Hacks
```

and am trying to compile the project dumper.sln, inside the Source folder.
However, I get 1000+ errors like identifier "u16" is undefined.

It seems that Visual Studio doesn't understand Cpp11.

I've changed the language standard in Project Properties do C++14 and C++17, but neither work.

I would appreciate any help I can get.

PS: to try to build To build you have to install glib with Nuget, and add the .\packages\glib.2.36.2.11\build\native\include\glib folder to the dependecies, otherwise, glibconfig.h is not found

Comment: `u16` is not defined by the C++ standard, 11 or otherwise. The problem is in the project, not the compiler.

Comment: How do you compile this code? the github project has a `C/core/common.h` header file that defines the type `u16`.

Comment: You are correct, there the definition is indeed in common.h. I assume then that the project that should be built is instead C/Mizzurna Falls.sln. However, I'm getting the command pmake exited with code 9009.

Answer (score 2):

There's no `u16` in standard C++. You have these fixed width types: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Either your project needs to define `u16` itself or it's relying on some non-standard tool chain which defines it.

Answer (score 0):

u8 u16 u32 and u64 are used in kernel programming and that is done in C.